# What is the difference between DEFAULT NULL and the CHECKBOX NULL mysql?

Tags: mysql, null

What is the difference between DEFAULT NULL and the CHECKBOX NULL mysql?

I can set default as NULL or there is a checkbox below which I can check to say NULL?

What's the difference?

Comment: What do you mean by CHECKBOX NULL? Are you referring to an UI like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: There is a select/check box that can be ticked upon creating which has to the left the value of NULL in myAdmin

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Having a column DEFAULT NULL means if you don't set a value for the column, it will be NULL by default.

Having a column NULL(able) means it can be NULL at all, otherwise it will require you to set a value for the column, either by default or in the insert query. Only check that box if the value is supposed to be optional.

Comment: Optional as in, the user may or may not fill in their phone number in a form?

Comment: Exactly, NULL is a value that usually indicates the absence of a value, if you disallow NULL, you require one.

Comment: What's benefit of the null checkbox? increases speed? decrease size of the database? is it true?

Comment: @joachim isakssom I do not understand what you mean by 'it can be null at all' can anyone clarify. Thanks